# Smallest code to return sum of all characters in an array of strings

Tags: code-golf

Smallest code to return sum of all characters of an array of C-strings, including null-byte-terminattor of each string in the array.

example in C:

```
    const char *a[] = { "abc", "bdef", "cee", "deee" };
    size_t n = sumOfAllBytes(a);
    printf("n = %d\n", n); // n = 18
```

e.g.,

```
   strlen(a[0]) + 1 + ... + strlen(a[n])
```

where `n` is `array-size-1`, ie, the last elemet in the array, in this case, `deee` word. Note that `n = 4` (starting from 0 as C does)

Each character is an ASCII character in C it's 1 byte-size.

Comment: How do you define the value of each character?

Comment: by `sizeof(char)` = 1, e.g, strlen("abc") + sizeof('0') = 4

Comment: @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳  Looks like it is the count of each character: 14 chars + 4 null-byte-terminators = 18.

Comment: Do you have to create a complete program, or is it OK to write only a function with an array as parameter?

Comment: Only the function with some usage example.

Comment: That's not the sum of characters. That's the number of characters.

Comment: How do you know how many strings are in the array? Your example doesn't have any sort of length argument or sentinel value to indicate it.

Comment: How is this `sum of all characters` or `sumOfAllBytes`. Isn't it just a count, rather than a sum? At best `sumoflengthsof`, but not sum of characters or bytes.

Comment: @user2357112: In C it's by `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])`

Comment: @BillWoodger: I mean sum of the length of all string in the array. It isn't count. My previously comment show how count is. It's sum:    `strlen(a[0]) + 1 + ... + strlen(a[n])`

Comment: @Jack: Doesn't work. The function only receives a pointer to the first element of the array; the size information isn't available.

Comment: @user2357112: I' don't limited you to don't pass the `count` of elements in the array by no means. You can write an extra parameter called size and then pass `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` which will give the `count` of elements in the array not all many the sum of length of each string into it. In this case you need to something like a loop from `0` to `size` plus `strlen(a[i])`.

Comment: Also, you can use any language you want to, if you do C++ there's a trick with C++ using templates. It just make easy know the count of array passed by parameter without an extra parameter also array itself. It does work fine. I have both C and C++ working version (the initial challenge was limited to C/C++ but I changed in order to everybody join)

Comment: You say "array of C-strings", so presumably the program needs to actually use C-style strings.

Comment: You say sum of bytes, sum of characters. You are asking for neither of those things. It is a count of characters, or bytes, including delimiters, or a sum of the lengths, including delimiters. It is *not* the sum of bytes/characters. This is computers.

Comment: @user2357112: Since I removed the limit to use C or C++ language people are using other languages and just assuming there's a 0 byte at end of string just adding plus one in the length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## GolfScript [4 bytes]

```
n*,)
```

There are no functions in GolfScript, so you should use a standard input instead:

```
["abc" "bdef" "cee" "deee"]
n*,)

>>> 18
```

**DEMO:** http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=WyJhYmMiICJiZGVmIiAiY2VlIiAiZGVlZSJdCgpuKiwp

Comment: I need to learn GolfScript. :)

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```haskell
succ.length.unwords
```

Edit: Removed two bytes thanks to [ais523](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62131/ais523)!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to PPCG! We allow submitting anonymous functions here; you don't need to name them. As such, you could remove the `s=` to save two bytes, as the submission evaluates to an expression of function type as it is. (I'm also curious as to whether there's a way to golf down the `succ` into something shorter, but all the possibilities I've thought of, such as `(+1)`, are the same number of bytes or longer.) Incidentally, you can use `#` or `##` at the start of a line for heading-bold (`#` is larger); that's the formatting most people use for their answers.

Comment: It also took me some time to figure out that this answer was correct. Often it's a good idea to include a link to an online interpreter that shows the program working. [Here's](https://tio.run/##DcU5DoAgEADAr2yoIDH8wB/YWRoLjlWMuBiOWBjfvtLMBFNOjJEvcxCM4BO8cLc61zwRyBLSA1Jyac7piLTXoBs9KfvCahHGOjEI63HrOcSux96qFHz8Aw) one for your program; you could edit it into your answer.

Comment: By the way, don't worry about the downvote: it was caused by a [bug in the Stack Exchange software](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276269/347902), not made by an actual user.

Comment: You can use `unlines` instead of `unwords` and drop the `succ`, because `unlines` adds a final newline: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfmfm5iZp2CrkJKvUK1QUFoSXFLkk6egUZyRX66gofE/JzUvvSRDrzQvJzMvtfi/ZrRSYlKyko5SUkpqGpBKTk0FkimpQCpWU1Oh9j8A "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica <s>31</s> 29 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to numbermaniac

```
StringLength[""<>#]+Length@#&
```

Example

```
StringLength[""<>#]+Length@#&@{ "abc", "bdef", "cee", "deee" }
```

> 18

Comment: I don't think you need to assign the function name to a variable to be a valid answer, so you could save 2 bytes there.

Comment: @numermaniac, you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## bash+coreutils - function body 10 bytes

```
sumOfAllBytes()(wc -c<<<$@)
```

Call as follows:

```
$ a=("abc" "bdef" "cee" "deee")
$ sumOfAllBytes ${a[@]}
18
$
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, function body: 15 bytes

```perl
sub sumOfAllBytes{!!@_+length"@_"}
```

Function `sumOfAllBytes` returns the sum of the string lengths including a "virtual" terminator byte. Perl does not have the concept of terminating a string with a null byte.

A variant without a "terminating byte":

```perl
sub sumOfAllBytes{$"=$;@_+length"@_"}
```

**Byte count:** The body of the functions are 15 or 17 bytes (with or without terminator). 7 bytes must be added, if the whole function with one-byte name should be counted.

**Test with degolfed version:**

```perl
sub sumOfAllBytes {
    # the argument(s) are put into array @_ by Perl
    !!@_ +       # short for: @_ ? 1 : 0
                 # (if the array is empty nothing should be added)
    length "@_"  # The array elements are interpolated into the double-
                 # quoted string; the elements are separated by a space ($").
    # without explicit return statement, the value of the last
    # statement is returned.
}

@a = qw[abc bdef cee deee];
print sumOfAllBytes(@a), "\n"; # prints 18
```

Answer (score 1):

## Rebol (body: 18 chars, function: 30 chars)

```
1 + length? form x
```

Usage example in Rebol console:

```
>> f: func[x][1 + length? form x]

>> f ["abc" "bdef" "cee" "deee"]
== 18
```

Answer (score 1):

### C, 78 minus declaration of a[]

Assumes 64 bit target and a[] containing at least one string.

```
char *a[]={"abc","bdef","cee","deee"};
f(int i){return strlen(a[i])+1+(i?f(i-1):0);}
main(){return f(sizeof(a)/8-1);}
```

To see the result, invoke thusly:

```
$ ./whatever || echo $?
```

Answer (score 1):

## c preprocessor macros, 94 chars

The example in the question is not doable in c as a regular function as the function would have no idea the size of the array if just a pointer to the array is passed in.  But we can do this as a couple of preprocessor macros:

```
#define c(s) sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0])-1
#define sumOfAllBytes(s) s[c(s)]-s[0]+strlen(s[c(s)])+1
```

We assume that the array is declared, defined and initialised as in the question.  That way the strings should be laid out sequentially in memory.  We can then subtract the address of the first element from the last element and add the `strlen()` of the last element.  No need to loop over all elements and `strlen()`.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell 24

```
s=sum.(map$(+1).length)
```

Usage, in ghci:

```
ghci> s ["abc", "bdef", "cee", "deee"]
18
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java: 56 characters (body) 74 characters (full method)

*Hey, this is as good as it gets in Java!*

This is the method:

```
int z(String[]a){int s=0;for(String b:a)s+=b.length();return s+a.length;}
```

The main code is just *56* characters (witout spaces and comments):

```
int s=0;            // The sum variable.
for(String b:a)     // The 'for each' loop is handy
    s+=b.length();  // Adding the length of each String
return s+a.length;  // Adding the length of the array
```

**Calling this function:**

```
int answer = z(new String[]{ "abc", "bdef", "cee", "deee" }); // Stores 18
```

Comment: I know it's been over three years, but you can golf two bytes by changing `int s=0;` to `int s=a.length;` and removing the `+a.length` in the return.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
JgIg+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fK90zXfv//2ilxKRkJR0FpaSU1DQQnZyaCqJSUoHcWAA)

-1 thanks to @Datboi

Comment: `JgIg+` should work as well

Comment: I have no idea how that works. `I` is supposed to read the current input as a `String`, and if the first input was consumed by `J`, how is it still reading the input, as an array no less? Unless they changed what `I` does... Weird...

Comment: As far as I know it will read the input as an array if it is in the form of  `[item1, item2, ...]`. To answer your second question: If there are no items on the stack nor in the input `I` will use a copy of the bottom input to pop. `Jg¹g+` should also work though

Comment: @Datboi yeah, I think they changed it since a year ago. A year ago I don't think that would've worked. Then again this is a 3 year old question, so this answer is non-competing anyway; just noticed that too lol.

Answer (score 0):

### C [body: 48 chars, function: 107 chars]

```
int f(const char** r, const char* c, const char** e) { 
  return r-e?1+(*c?f(r,c+1,e):f(r+1,*(r+1),e)):0; 
}
```

Ugly piece of code. Just trying to do it without loops by using recursion.

Call it this way:

```
    const char *a[] = { "abc", "bdef", "cee", "deee" };
    size_t n = f(a,*a,a+4);
    printf("n = %zu\n", n);
```

No warnings and result is OK:

```
$ gcc koe.c -Wall -Wextra -o koe
$ ./koe
n = 18
```

Answer (score 0):

## C - Loop:64, Recursion:56 (-18 for function body overhead)

### Loop

```
s(char*a[],int n){int r=0;for(;n;)r+=strlen(a[--n])+1;return r;}
```

### Recursion

```
r(char*a[],int n){return n?strlen(a[0])+1+r(a+1,n-1):0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP 5.3 - 60

```
array_sum(array_map(function($v){return strlen($v)+1;},$a));
```

Where `$a` is the array.

Comment: `<?=strlen(join(_,$_GET))+1;` should do the same

Answer (score 0):

### Python - <strike>55</strike> <strike>42</strike> 38

```python
def s(v):print sum(1+len(x)for x in v)
```

Comment: can be shortened some more: `def s(v):print sum(1+len(x)for x in v)` to 38 chars

Comment: Here's a TIO with a lambda instead, 32 bytes. https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/pfbBvzPycxNyklUaHMqrg0V8NQOyc1T6NCMy2/SKFCITNPoUzzf0FRZl6JQrFGtFJiUrKSjlJSSmoakEpOTQWSKalAKlbzPwA

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript - 42 characters without declaration

```
function s(x){return x.join(" ").length+1}
```

Usage:

```
a=["abc","bdef","cee","deee"];console.log(s(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

### D - <del>58</del> 54 bytes

```
int x(T)(T t){return reduce!"a+b.length"(t.length,t);}
```

This requires `std.algorithm`, so add the characters necessary for making that import if you want to.

Example of usage:

```
import std.stdio,std.algorithm;

int x(T)(T t){return reduce!"a+b.length"(t.length,t);}

void main(){
    writeln(x!(string[])(["abc","bdef","cee","deee"]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Fortran 90+ - 75 total, 23 for function alone

Unfortunately, Fortran doesn't allow for implicit typing of character strings, but we can abuse F77+F90 for golfing purposes. The whole program would be:

```
character*4::c(4)=["abc","bdef","cee","deee"];print*,sum(len_trim(c)+1);end
```

The function alone, written using a statement function would be

```
k(s)=sum(len_trim(s)+1)
```

which would be called using `print*,k(c)`.

Answer (score 0):

**in C# 34 Excluding  "string [] a=new [] { "abc", "bdef", "cee", "deee" };"**

```
   string [] a=new [] { "abc", "bdef", "cee", "deee" };
                var i=string.Join(" ",a).Length+1;
sol:2  
var j =  string.Concat(a).Length + a.Length;
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript - <strike>20</strike> 17 Characters

```
s.join().length+1
```

Assumes that the array of strings is in variable 's' and outputs the answer to the console.

Answer (score 0):

### APL 6

```
+/1+⍴¨a
```

where

```
a←"abc" "bdef" "cee" "deee"
```

yields

```
      +/1+⍴¨a
 18
```

Read as "Sum over 1 plus size of each element in a"

Comment: Isn't that 6? `+/1+⍴¨` Anyway, you can make it 4: [`⍴⊢,∊`](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%u2374%u22A2%2C%u220A%20%u22C4%20f%20%27abc%27%20%27bdef%27%20%27cee%27%20%27deee%27&run)

Answer (score 0):

**C#, 52** including variable declaration

```
int c=0;for(int i=0;i<a.Length;i++)c+=1+a[i].Length;
```

Uncompressed version for ease of reading:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    count += 1 + a[i].Length;
```

Answer (score 0):

## q/kdb+, 14 bytes

**Solution:**

```
sum 1+(#:)each
```

**Example:**

```
q)sum 1+(#:)each("abc";"bdef";"cee";"deee")
18
```

**Explanation:**

Evaluated right-to-left, thus:

```
// count (#:) length of each item in the list
q)(#:)each("abc";"bdef";"cee";"deee")
3 4 3 4
// add one to each item
q)1+ 3 4 3 4
4 5 4 5
// sum up the items
q)sum 4 5 4 5
18
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
KL‘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/b51HDjP///0crJSYlK@koKCWlpKaB6OTUVBCVkgqkYwE)

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 32 bytes

```
#(apply +(map(comp inc count)%))
```

[Composition](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/comp) FTW. Aww it is the same length as `#(apply +(count %)(map count %))`.

Answer (score 0):

## F#, 56 bytes

Still practicing with F#...

```
let f a=(a|>Seq.map String.length|>Seq.sum)+Seq.length a
```

Invoke with:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let sum = [| "abc"; "bdef"; "cee"; "deee" |] |> f
    printfn "%A" sum
    0
```

Comment: `Seq.sumBy(fun s->s.Length+1)`